# Plotting discontinuous xts timeseries on same plot in R?

Tags: r, merge, plot, xts

I'd like to be able to do a line plot of several discontinuous time series on the same screen in R, and am having trouble getting all data to appear at once:

```
require(xts)
require(xtsExtra)
df1=data.frame(a=1:30,b=3*1:30)
df1$b[2*1:15]=NA
df1A_xts=xts(df1,ISOdate(1900+1:30,1,1))
df1B_xts=xts(df1,ISOdate(1900+2*1:30,2,1))
df1_xts_merge=merge.xts(df1A_xts,df1B_xts)
```

Of course, when I plot as a point graph, everything shows up okay:

```
plot.xts(df1_xts_merge,screens=1,type="p",auto.legend=TRUE)
```

But when I try to plot one or more series as lines, the discontinuities cause trouble, e.g.:

```
plot.xts(df1_xts_merge,screens=1,auto.legend=TRUE)
```

How can I plot each of these series as a continuous line on the same set of axes?

Comment: Don't know, but it looks like it has to do with `NA`s.  This works: `plot(na.omit(df1A_xts[, 2]))`, but this doesn't `plot(df1A_xts[, 2])`

Comment: I agree that the NAs are the problem.  I'd be open to solutions that somehow combine the na.omit() datasets on a single plot.  I haven't figured out how to get that to work either.

Comment: Ok, this is a somewhat unsatisfying solution, but it works:
`plot(index(na.omit(df1A_xts)),na.omit(df1A_xts)$a,type="l")`
`lines(index(na.omit(df1A_xts)),na.omit(df1A_xts)$b,type="l")`
`lines(index(na.omit(df1B_xts)),na.omit(df1B_xts)$b,type="l")`
`lines(index(na.omit(df1B_xts)),na.omit(df1B_xts)$a,type="l")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xts and zoo behave consistent with the default plotting methods:

```
matplot(df1_xts_merge,type="l")
```

[image: default plotting via matplot]

You seem to want a plot of the lines interpolated through the points in your xts object, in which case `na.approx` or `na.spline` will be helpful:

```
plot(na.approx(df1_xts_merge),screens=1,auto.legend=TRUE)
```

[image: xtsExtra::plot.xts with na.approx]